# How to fix This kernal requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot error

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am using Virtualbox(Oracle)
Host - Win10(64bit)
Guest - Kali Linux(64bit iso)

My PC doesn't support virtualization. I have turned off Enable VT-x for the virtual machine in System tab(settings)

I am not getting the option to scroll for a 64-bit os type in Settings>General

The error - This kernal requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

If anybody know how to fix this error please help! as I can't run kali in some other way other than by virtual means.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox [requires hardware virtualisation when running 64-bit guests](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt), so if your PC doesn’t support hardware virtualisation, you won’t be able to run 64-bit Kali as a guest.

The 32-bit edition should however work fine; if you download one of [the 32-bit ISOs](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) you should be able to boot it.

Comment: okay I will download a 32bit iso and post the results soon